Redirect output of shell script with parameter to variable
I have a shell script called pwd.sh which I need to call within another shell script a.sh. I need to store the output of pwd.sh into a variable in a.sh. pwd.sh has a user enterable parameter while executing.
Is this possible?
#!/bin/sh
sh pwd.sh

This is how a.sh looks.

What does "has a user enterable parameter while executing" mean? Can you describe it in more detail? Is that paramet being prompted for? Do you want to pass it to a.sh and then pass it on to pwd.sh?

Yes, the parameter will be prompted for. and I need the output if pwd.sh to be stored in a variable within a.sh. No, the parameter value does not need to be passed to a.sh. I am only calling pwd.sh within a.sh.

Btw, you wrote bash as a tag, but use sh in the script.

Does pwd.sh prompt something to the user? If so, does it do it through /dev/tty, stderr or stdout?

What do you mean by "output"? Stdtout? stderr? Things printed directly to the console?
